How to specify different S3A credentials for each Spark read/write operation in PySpark?
I’m working with PySpark and need to configure different S3A credentials for various operations within the same Spark session. The reason I’m asking this is that I need to interact with multiple S3 hosts in the same session, and I’ll be running parallel jobs that require different credentials for each S3 host.
For example, I’d like to do something like this:
df = (spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("fs.s3a.bucket.my-bucket.access.key", minio_username)
  .option("fs.s3a.bucket.my-bucket.secret.key", minio_password)
  .option("fs.s3a.bucket.my-bucket.endpoint", minio_host)
  .load("s3a://my-bucket/my.csv"))

In this case, even though the Spark session has different S3A credentials set globally, I want it to use the credentials provided in this specific operation.
Is this possible? I’ve searched and tried various approaches, but so far, I haven’t found a solution that works. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

If you want different credentials per bucket (not per read/write within same bucket) then you can use Per-bucket configuration.

You configure per-bucket properties using the syntax spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket-name>.<configuration-key>. This lets you set up buckets with different credentials, endpoints, and so on.
For example, in addition to global S3 settings you can configure each bucket individually using the following keys:
# Set up authentication and endpoint for a specific bucket
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket-name>.aws.credentials.provider <aws-credentials-provider-class>
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket-name>.endpoint <aws-endpoint>

# Configure a different KMS encryption key for a specific bucket
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket-name>.server-side-encryption.key <aws-kms-encryption-key>



It's interesting. Is it only applicable for Databrick runtime or hadoop-aws module?

OSS, hadoop. Not databricks specific.

S3 credential setting in Spark is in application level, which means you can only configure it when you submit your Spark job or create your Spark session, but not single transformation or action level.
Not sure how big the file you want to read, I think you can use AWS python SDK (boto3) to create multiple session and read the data first, and then convert it to Spark DataFrame. Or you need to create multiple Spark session and save the data into a same bucket as a staging area.

I tried to create a new spark session but getOrCreate always returns the same spark when the master is the same.

@Alperİnan, "get"OrCreate() does what the name says. If you want a new session then use newSession()

@Alperİnan It's because you already have a created Spark Session. Just like Kashyap mentioned, you can use a newSession, or you can stop your existing session first.

all you get are per-bucket credentials, unless you want to get into the depths of implementing your own AWS SDK credential provider -and even there I'm dubious it'd work.
But:

buckets are differentiated by the hostname of the URL
s3a fs has support for AWS access points. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Configuring_S3_AccessPoints_usage_with_S3A

if you were targeting AWS S3 I'd say "create a different access point and use the mapping of "a virtual hostname" to AP to let you have different credentials by using URLs of the virtual hostname"
For minio, I can't see that working unless you can somehow map different bucket names to the same bucket with different credentials. And you'd have to fix those credentials at cluster startup.
that leaves providing your own implementation of the AWSCredentialsProvider interface which somehow picks up new values. Even I could see a way to get the options down, I would not recommend going down that way: it is hard work and you'd have to deal with cached FS instances (you can disable that for a bit of a performance hit).
